# How to Insert Data in magento 2 database table programatically

Tags: magento2, database, programmatically

We want to insert data in database table.
My site is in magento 2.
Any one help me for insert data in database table.

```
namespace Agtech\Productstockupdate\Block\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
protected $productFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, 
    array $data = []) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function updateStock($product_sku,$product_QTY)
{
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);

    if($product->getStatus() == 2){ // 2 => Disable , 1 => Enable

        $product->setStatus(1);

        if($product->getStatus() == 1){
            $product->setStockData([
                'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                'qty' => $productQty 
            ]);

            $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus([
                'qty' => $productQty,
                'is_in_stock' => 1
            ]); 
        }

        $product->setStatus(2);

        try {
            $product->save(); 
            echo 'Quantity update of SKU => '.$product->getSku().'<br/>'; 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getException();
        }

    }else{

        $product->setStockData([
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => $productQty
        ]);

        $product->setQuantityAndStockStatus([
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'is_in_stock' => 1
        ]); 

        try {
            $product->save(); 
            echo 'Quantity update of SKU => '.$product->getSku().'<br/>'; 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getException();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In which table you want to insert that data?

Comment: Any new table create in database and insert in it. we want two columns.

Comment: Magento uses CRUD models to insert data, you can read up on it here - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1):

We can insert the data by following way:

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Controller;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
 
class YourController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;
 
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     */
    protected $resource;
 
    protected $connection;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ...
        ...
        ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->messageManager       = $messageManager;
        ...
        ...
        $this->resource             = $resource;
        $this->connection           = $resource->getConnection();
 
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        .....................
        .....................
        $this->yourCustomFunction();
        .....................
        .....................
    }
 
    public function insertMultiple($table, $data)
    {
        try {
            $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName($table);
            return $this->connection->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Cannot insert data.'));
        }
    }
 
    public function yourCustomFunction()
    {
        try {
            $yourData = [
                ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'John', 'age' => 22],
                ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mary', 'age' => 23],
                ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Sam', 'age' => 24]
            ];
            
            $tableName = 'your_table_name';
            $this->insertMultiple($tableName, $yourData);
            
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Successfully inserted data.') );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Cannot save data.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Hope this helps. Thanks!**

Comment: @Anil Here you want to save the data by product id or product sku?

Comment: here is our custom data; not magento default. If you want any name change so dont worry.

Comment: @Anil If you want to insert data into custom table then you can use my way, please try it.

Comment: Is these use with Block file ?

Comment: No, here I am doing this with controller file.

Comment: @Anil at least upvote him if he has helped you..

Comment: @FaisalSheikh, why have you created the function **insertMultiple** ? I think you could have directly used the function.

Comment: @VishalParkash for better understanding, but you can save the data directly as well.